# Why can't I authenticate a Django user created from a custom manage.py command?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-users, django-manage.py

This one has me completely stumped. I have a model which extends the base User model in Django, so I am writing a custom `manage.py` command to create superusers. It seems to be working fine, but for some reason any users that I create via this custom command cannot be authenticated by Django. When I check the database, the users are indeed being created and all of the information is correct.

Here's the code for my custom command in a file called `createadmin.py` (I've omitted the bits of code irrelevant to the problem):

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Creates a Django admin user'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        username = raw_input('Admin username: ')
        password = raw_input('Admin password: ')

        try:
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, password, '')
            new_user.is_superuser = True
            new_user.is_staff = True
            new_user.save()
            self.stdout.write('Admin created successfully')
        except:
            self.stdout.write('Sorry, there was a problem creating a new user in the database.')
```

Now, if I run this command using `python manage.py createadmin`, everything seems to work and the user is created in the database.

To demonstrate the problem, here is the output from testing with `createadmin` and `shell`:

**createadmin**

```
Admin username: testadmin
Admin password: admin
Admin created successfully
```

**shell**

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='testadmin')
>>> user.is_superuser
True
>>> user.is_active
True
>>> user.is_staff
True
>>> authenticate(username='testadmin', password='admin') is None
True
```

So as you can see, the user exists, but I cannot authenticate them. I get similar behavior when I try to authenticate the user on the server from within a `login` view. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second positional argument to `create_user` is email, not password.

You should use keyword arguments:

```
new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, password=password)
```

Comment: Man you are my lifesaver! Thanks so much